# What's the difference, content-wise, between the "Sorcery!" mobile games and books?

Tags: sorcery

Due to obvious reasons, not 100% certain this is the correct stack exchange for this, but here goes.

I've been playing the "Sorcery!" mobile games for a little while, and while the first one ("The Shamutanti Hills") has some minor difference (mostly expanded introduction and dialogs), the second one ("Kharé - Cityport of Traps") has a lot more content changes and additions. Some of these things I verified with the book - added encounters, additional options for back-tracking, etc.

I've been looking for a breakdown of all the changes and additions between the games and the original book, certain that someone, somewhere on the internet, have already compiled a comprehensive list. But I wasn't able to find one. Does anyone remember the original books well enough for a detailed breakdown, or can point me to an online resource for it?

Comment: Old question, but just thought I'd throw out there that the differences get more and more significant as the series goes on - 3 and 4 in particular have so much added to them that it might be easier to list the similarities than the differences.